# Speedup superlinear of the quicksort algorithm

Tags: c, quicksort

I've implemented both a sequential version and a parallel version of quicksort.

I've used to verify the speedup the worst case of quicksort for my implementation: the source array is already sorted and in my case the pivot is always the first element of the array.

So, the partition generates two sets one containing the elements lesser than the pivot and another with the elements higher than pivot having namely n - 1 elements where n is the number of elements of the array being passed as the argument of quicksort function. The recursion depth has size N -1 where N is the number of elements of the original array passed as argument for the quicksort function.

Obs: The sets are actually represented by two variables containing the initial and the final position of the array part that correspondends either the elements are smaller than the pivot and the elements are higher than the pivot. The whole division are happening in place, what means no new array is created on process. The difference of the sequential for the parallel is in the parallel version more than one array is created where the elements  are divided equally between them (sorted as the sequential case). For the junction of elements in the parallel case the algorithm merge was used.

The speedup obtained was higher than the theoric, it means with two threads the speeedup achieved was more than 2x compared to the sequential version (3x to be more precise) and with 4 threads the speedup was 10x.

The computer where I ran the threads is a 4 cores machine (Phenom II X4) running Ubuntu Linux 10.04, 64 bits if I am not wrong. The compiler is gcc 4.4 and no flags were passed for the compiler with exception of the inclusion of library pthread for the parallel implementation;

So, does someone know the reason for the superlinear speedup achieved? Can someone give some any pointer, please?

Comment: Does the X4 have any "turbo boost" or other automatic dynamic scaling?

Comment: Also, do the results hold for *random data* or is it just an artifact of *worst case* data?

Answer (score 2):

It would really be best to use some performance analyzer to dig into
this in more detail, but my first guess is that this kind of super
linear speed up is caused by the fact that you get more cache space
if you add threads. In that way, more data will be read from cache.
Since the cost of a memory transfer is really high, this can easily
improve performance.

Are you using [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) to evaluate your maximum speedup ?

Hope this helps.

Comment: +1 CTZStef's explanation is usual the standard explanation for superlinear speedup. I have also encountered the effect with Quicksort which scaled almost linearly on 48 cores. There, the reason was that the first  split of the vector in Quicksort algorithm was executed sequentially but all other subsequent splits were executed in parallel with superlinear speedup. The final result was close to linear speedup.

Answer (score 2):

If you see a 3x speedup with two threads versus one, and a 10x speedup with four threads versus one, something fishy is going on.

Amdahl's law states that speedup is 1/(1-P+P/S), where P is the portion of the algorithm which is parallel and S is the speedup factor of the parallel portion.  Assuming that S=4 for four cores (the best possible result), we find that P=2.5, which is impossible (it has to be between 0 and 1, inclusive).

Put another way, if you could get a 10x improvement with 4 cores, then you could simply use one core to simulate four cores and still get a 2.5x improvement (or thereabouts).

Put yet another way, four cores over one second perform fewer operations than one core over ten seconds.  So the parallel version is actually performing fewer operations, and if that is the case there is no reason why the serial version couldn't also perform fewer operations.

Possible conclusions:

- Something could be wrong with your sequential version.  Perhaps it is optimized poorly.
- Something could be wrong with your parallel versions.  They could be incorrect.
- The measurement could be performed incorrectly.  This is quite common.

Impossible conclusions:

- This algorithm scales superlinearly.